# Split docx into multiple documents and maintain page numbers

Tags: ms-word, docx

If I have a 10 page document with the first 6 pages section 1, the next 3 pages section 2 and the last page section 3, how do i make 3 new documents with Docx 1 have pages 1-6, Docx 2 have pages 7-9, and Docx 3 have page 1?

Each Docx needs to start with the page number from the original docx

new docx 1 pages 1-6 and labeled page 1, ..., 6
new docx 2 pages 7-9 and labeled page 7, 8 9
new docx 3 page 10 and labeled page 10

Assume that the page size, margin, font size, etc does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Following method can split Word document by section breaks. But it is hard to maintain the page number unless you turn off the 'Link to Previous' (head or footer not inherited from the previous one) property between each sections in the original document.

```
using Spire.Doc;

namespace SplitBySections
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.docx");

            for (int i = 0; i < doc.Sections.Count; i++)
            {
                Document newWord = new Document();
                newWord.Sections.Add(doc.Sections[i].Clone());
                newWord.SaveToFile(String.Format(@"output_{0}.docx", i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```